# select row based on the condition of number apparence for first time

Tags: r, select, row, conditional-statements

I would like to find rows in which defined number appear (for example 2) for first time?

For example:

```
group <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")
value <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)
GOAL <- c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE")
data <- data.frame(group, value, GOAL)
data
```

In the column "GOAL" would be the result.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way assumes each `group` has at least one 2. Although your sample data is ordered by group, the approach used here doesn't depend on this.

```
# given vector v, return vector of FALSEs, except at the first 2
f <- function(v) replace(logical(length(v)), which(v == 2)[1], TRUE)
transform(data, GOAL=as.logical(ave(value, group, FUN=f)))
#    group value  GOAL
# 1      a     1 FALSE
# 2      a     1 FALSE
# 3      a     2  TRUE
# 4      a     2 FALSE
# 5      a     1 FALSE
# 6      b     1 FALSE
# 7      b     2  TRUE
# 8      b     1 FALSE
# 9      b     2 FALSE
# 10     b     3 FALSE
```

The call to `as.logical` is necessary if you want `TRUE`/`FALSE`, since `ave` always returns a numeric vector. Without `as.logical`, you get 0s and 1s.

Comment: All solutions are great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do

```
valueFirst <- 2
data[data$value==valueFirst,][1,]
```

Then you have the row. If you want only GOAL as output:

```
data[data$value==valueFirst,][1,3]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a vector which gives the first occurrence within each `group`.