# Select one row in a group based on the first appearance of a value

Tags: r, select

This question expands on [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15677073/2359271) that I asked yesterday.

I would like to find rows inside groups in which a defined number appears for first time. If this number doesn't appear in the group than the next highest number will be used.

For example:

```
group <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")
value <- c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2)
GOAL <- c("FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE")
data <- data.frame(group, value, GOAL)
data
```

First I would like to search the group for the value 3. If it is present, the row with first number 3 in the group is marked as "TRUE" and if not than look for the first value 2 and so on. At the end each group has only one "TRUE". So the "GOAL" column is the expected result.

Comment: Much easier to help if you show the current data frame (`data`) and then what you want it to look like.

Comment: Your description is not consistent with the "GOAL" you give as an example. Group "c" contains a 3. so the group "c" GOAL should be c("FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE"); This is because you say "if there is no number 3 in the group then look for first number 2 and so on" ....

Comment: The question is understandable. Just please mention that the GOAL column is the expected result.

Comment: Aditya and agstudy thank you. I have edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result you describe by replacing `which(v==2)[1]` in the answer I gave to your last question with `which.max(v)`.

```
f <- function(v) replace(logical(length(v)), which.max(v), TRUE)
transform(data, GOAL=as.logical(ave(value, group, FUN=f)))
#    group value  GOAL
# 1      a     1 FALSE
# 2      a     3  TRUE
# 3      a     2 FALSE
# 4      a     1 FALSE
# 5      b     1 FALSE
# 6      b     1 FALSE
# 7      b     2  TRUE
# 8      b     1 FALSE
# 9      c     2 FALSE
# 10     c     3  TRUE
# 11     c     3 FALSE
# 12     c     2 FALSE
```

Comment: wasn't aware of which.max; with that you can have a tapply solution as well: dFrame$GOAL<-as.vector(unlist(tapply(dFrame$value,dFrame$group,FUN=function(x){ v<-rep(FALSE,length(x)); v[which.max(x)]<-TRUE; return (v)})))

Comment: @AdityaSihag the downside to using `tapply` is that it would assume the data is ordered by `group`. `ave` avoids this assumption.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde would it be possible to change the function in this way that if there would be more numbers with the same value inside the group that it will select the last one in the column? For examples in group "c" the second value 3 would be selected (ID = 11).

Comment: @MtS Yes, please submit another question and I'll add the answer.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde I submit the question and hope that it is more understandable? :(

Answer (score 2):

Or in the base package , similar to @MatthewPlourde solution but one liner one:

```
transform(data, GOAL= ave(value,group,
        FUN=function(x)seq(x)==which.max(x))> 0)
```

**EDIT** get the last maximum.

`which.max` determines the location of the **first maximum**.  it is equivalent to `head(which(x == max(x)),1)`. To get The last maximum , you can do something like this:

```
transform(data, GOAL= ave(value,group,
                          FUN=function(x)seq(x)==tail(which(x==max(x)),1))> 0)
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. My understanding is that OP wants just the first max value to be `TRUE`. `transform` here is also missing a column name.

Comment: R is a shed full of cat-skinning tools. I love the `replace` function, so I probably use it even in cases when something terser would suffice. Although, one could argue about clarity.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde I didn't know this function before, but I agree your example is more readable and traduce exactly what the OP had expressed.

Answer (score 1):

try this code snippet:

```
 groups<-c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c");
 values<-c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2);
 dFrame<-data.frame(groups,values);

 max_values<-as.vector(unlist(tapply(dFrame$values,dFrame$groups,max)));
 length_values<-as.vector(unlist(tapply(dFrame$values,dFrame$groups,length)));

 dFrame$GOAL<-as.vector(unlist(sapply(1:length(max_values),FUN=function(i,x,y,z){
   v<-rep(FALSE,z[i]);
   ind<-match(y[i],as.vector(unlist(x[i])));
   v[ind]<-TRUE;
   return (v);
   },x=tapply(dFrame$values,dFrame$groups,identity),
   y=max_values,z=length_values)));
```